# Cisco switch, white residue in switch ports

Tags: hardware, switch

I have 2 cisco small business switches, unknown age and provenance, both have developed a white residue on some of the switch ports as below image:

[image: switch port residue]
[image: switch port residue close up]

Any ideas what causes this?  It looks a little to me as if it could be capacitor gunk related?

Comment: Could it be [talc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talc)? That stuff is used in patch cables.

Comment: That's possible, I guess, but the cables would have had to be absolutely smothered in the stuff.

Comment: Assuming there is no warranty on these switches I would pop the case off and see what it looks like inside.

Answer (score 1):

Some things come to mind:

- Some form of dust/dirt (chalk, talc, cement, gypsum, flour, salt). Does it come off if you plug a cable in/out a couple of times ?
  Shouldn't effect operation, but check the fan's that they aren't clogged first. (Use an air-duster.)
- Could be some form of corrosion (rust). If that is the case I would dispose of the switches. No telling what has happened to the electronics on the inside in that case.

How to tell the difference: If it is dust/dirt it just sits on the surface. It can be stuck a bit (due to humidity) but you should be able to wipe it of fairly easily without leaving a trace.
If it is corrosion it has chemically bonded with the metal: It will be harder to get of and usually it will leave a rough and/or discolored spot or even scratches behind.